# How to create update delete Google contacts using gdata in android

Tags: android, gdata, google-api-client, google-contacts-api

I've tried more methode to create update and delete google contacts using gdata jars and it wasn't working so help me to realize this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

> The Google Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts. Contacts are stored in the user's Google Account; most Google services have access to the contact list.
>
> Your client application can use the Google Contacts API to create new contacts, edit or delete existing contacts, and query for contacts that match particular criteria
>
> *Creating contacts*
>
> - To create a new contact, send an authorized `POST` request to the user's contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.
>
> The URL is of the form:
>
> `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full`
>
> *Updating contacts*
>
> - To update a contact, first retrieve the contact entry, modify the data and send an authorized `PUT` request to the contact's edit URL with the modified contact entry in the body.
>
> The URL is of the form:
>
> `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/full/{contactId}`
>
> *Deleting contacts*
>
> - To delete a contact, send an authorized `DELETE` request to the contact's edit URL.
>
> The URL is of the form:
>
> `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}`

Here is a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/contacts-api-20-and-above) that may help you implement the above operations.

Hope this helps!